# Can't Convert JavaFX Datepicker date to a specified date format

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

Cannot convert javaFX Datepicker date to a specific(dd-MM-yyyy) date format.
here i using two Methods using SimpleDateFormat, but i got some errors like these.

when using this method

```
String testDateString = dpfrom.getValue().toString();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date d1 = df.parse(testDateString);
            System.out.println("Date in dd/MM/yyyy format is: "+df.format(d1));
```

the error message is:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-09-23"
```

while using this method:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date d1= sdf.parse(dpfrom.getValue().toString());
                System.out.println(d1);
```

i got this Output:

```
Fri Mar 11 00:00:00 IST 29
```

but i want the output like this:

```
23-09-2019
```

please help me to solve this issue.
I hope you guys to solve this problem.Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    private void dateTest() {
        try {
            String testDateString = "2019-09-23";
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date d1 = df.parse(testDateString);
            System.out.println(d1);
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String d2 = df.format(d1);
            System.out.println(d2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

output

```
Mon Sep 23 00:00:00 ICT 2019
23-09-2019
```

in your case change testDateString to dpfrom.getValue().toString();

Comment: @ Erwin, Thank you for your valuable answer.its work fine for me

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged your question as Java8 JavaFX8 question. Here is a more Java-8 fashion answer with `LocalDate` :

```
 String static final DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd"
 String datePickerValue = dpfrom.getValue().toString();
 DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN);
 LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(datePickerValue, dtf);
```

This is actually the new Java Time API since Java 8 (java.time) package

Answer (score 0):

Trying to convert `LocalDate` to `String` and then try to parse it as a `Date` is a bad idea. Simply use `DateTimeFormatter` to convert to a string directly:

```
final String format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
System.out.println("Date in " + format + " format is: " + formatter.format(d1));
```